# Row data disappears when a JTable row is deselected

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a simple `JTable`. When a row is selected, it is highlighted as expected (see image):

[image: Row selected (Ok)]

But when the row is deselected, the row data disappears (see image):

[image: Row deselected (not Ok)]

I am seeing this on Linux running the Java 11 JDK shipped with JetBrains IntelliJ.

Here's a self-contained example to reproduce the problem:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.setModel(new AbstractTableModel()
        {
            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int column)
            {
                return "Item";
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount()
            {
                return 10;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount()
            {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
            {
                return col == 0 ? "Test string #" + row : "";
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test JTable");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(table);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 200));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using your code, and I don't see any obvious glaring errors in the code either

Comment: Does it have anything to do with how if the column is NOT 0 then it displays "" based on your ternary operator? A null or no columns selected is not zero after all

Comment: @experimentunit1998X: I'm not sure why the OP's `getValueAt(...)` is structured the way that it is structured, but with the current table and model, the column should never be anything *but* `0` within the method.

Comment: how do you deselect the row? even if  ctrl-click on windows, a border remains at this item. in your screenshot it seems that no border exists. weird

Comment: In my testing, I added a JButton: `JButton clearSelectionBtn = new JButton("Clear Selection");  clearSelectionBtn.addActionListener(e -> {  table.clearSelection();  });`

Comment: still cant reproduce either (testing in windows though).

Comment: @Apostolos: same, and also using Windows 10

Comment: I am able to reproduce it, but it is not due to the getValueAt()

Comment: when the row is deselected (i pressed ctrl + click) the row disappears, but once i click anywhere else, the row value returns to normal. Is this some default behaviour of Jtable during ctrl+click event?

Comment: please is there the same result by override setValueAt, I'm sure in that

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels helooo, I'm glad to see you still here

Comment: @mKorbel: well, good to see you too, my friend!

Comment: could it be the drag selection on ctrl click? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is caused by the following known bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8202702.

Btw I have now been able to reproduce the problem in Windows 10 as well, using OpenJDK 11.

The linked bug report refers to a different use case (rows are selected and deselected from a `MouseListener`), however I have verified that the underlying problem is the same, and the "workaround" (overwriting the getSelectedRow() method in JTable to return -2 instead of -1) works, although that's obviously not a proper fix.

I have been able to work around the issue in a more robust way by registering a selection listener (`jtable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(...)`) and triggering a repaint when a row is deselected.